# Is there a regular expression way to replace a set of characters with another set (like shell tr command)?

Tags: java, regex, replace

The shell [`tr`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tr.htm) command support replace one set of characters with another set. 
For example, `echo hello | tr [a-z] [A-Z]` will tranlate `hello` to `HELLO`.

In java, however, I must replace each character individually like the following

```
"10 Dogs Are Racing"
    .replaceAll ("0", "０")
    .replaceAll ("1", "１")
    .replaceAll ("2", "２")
    // ...
    .replaceAll ("9", "９")
    .replaceAll ("A", "Ａ")
    // ...
;
```

The [apache-commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html) library provides a convenient [`replaceChars`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) method to do such replacement.

```
// half-width to full-width
System.out.println
(
    org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.replaceChars
    (
        "10 Dogs Are Racing",
        "0123456789ABCDEFEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        "０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＥＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ"
    )
);
// Result:
// １０ Ｄｏｇｓ Ａｒｅ Ｒａｃｉｎｇ
```

But as you can see, sometime the searchChars/replaceChars are too long (also too boring, please find a duplicated character in it if you want), and can be expressed by a simple regular expression `[0-9A-Za-z]`/`[０-９Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ]`. Is there a regular expression way to achieve that ?

Comment: Short answer: No. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is no direct way to do this, constructing your own utility function to use in combination with `replaceChars` is relatively simple. The version below accepts simple character classes, without `[` or `]`; it does not do class negation (`[^a-z]`).

For your use case, you could do:

```
StringUtils.replaceChars(str, charRange("0-9A-Za-z"), charRange("０-９Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ"))
```

Code:

```
public static String charRange(String str) {
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    char ch;
    for(int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++) {
        ch = str.charAt(index);
        if(ch == '\\') {
            if(index + 1 >= str.length()) {
                throw new PatternSyntaxException(
                    "Malformed escape sequence.", str, index
                );
            }
            // special case for escape character, consume next char:
            index++;
            ch = str.charAt(index);
        }
        if(index + 1 >= str.length() || str.charAt(index + 1) != '-') {
            // this was a single char, or the last char in the string
            ret.append(ch);
        } else {
            if(index + 2 >= str.length()) {
                throw new PatternSyntaxException(
                    "Malformed character range.", str, index + 1
                );
            }
            // this char was the beginning of a range
            for(char r = ch; r <= str.charAt(index + 2); r++) {
                ret.append(r);
            }
            index = index + 2;
        }
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```

Produces:

```
0-9A-Za-z : 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
０-９Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ : ０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ
```

Comment: i take a look at source code of `java.util.regex.Pattern`, and want to extract the character class parsing part, then realize it's difficult compared to write a small function to deal simple character class (just simple grouping & range). then your answer comes up :)

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 `Pattern` has to build a state machine rather than just a string, so it's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

*(some extra characters so that SO will allow me to post my otherwise succinct answer)*