# Why the second argument is not being taken as regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I came across an interesting question on java regex
[Is there a regular expression way to replace a set of characters with another set (like shell tr command)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010090/is-there-a-regular-expression-way-to-replace-a-set-of-characters-with-another-se)
So I tried the following:

```
                String a = "abc";
                a = a.replaceAll("[a-z]", "[A-Z]");
```

Now if I get print a the output is

```
                [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]
```

Here I think the compiler is taking the first argument as gegex, but not the second argument.

So is there any problem with this code or something else is the reason???

Comment: The answer to that question is a quite big and clear »No«. Why do you think that would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way replaceAll works.

See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Comment: Thank you, I got the your point. I should have looked in the API carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the linked question is a quite clear »No«, so this should come as no surprise.

As you can see from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the second argument is indeed a regular string that is used as replacement:

> **Parameters:**
>
> - `regex` – the regular expression to which this string is to be matched
> - `replacement` – the string to be substituted for each match

Answer (score 1):

second argument is simple String that will get substituted according to [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn lower case to upper case, there is a toUpperCase function available in String class. For equivalent functionality to `tr` utility, I think there is no support in Java (up to Java 7).

The replacement string is usually take literally, except for the sequence `$n` where n denotes the number of the capturing group in the regex. This will use captured string from the match as replacement.

Comment: I didn't mean to convert the lower case to uppercase. I just wanted to know how the regex works for this kind if thing.

Answer (score 0):

I consider regex as a way to express a condition (i.e does a given string match this expression). With that in mind, what you are asking would mean "please replace what matches in my string with ... another condition" which doesn't make much sens.

Now by trying to understand what you are looking for, it ssems to me that you want to find some automatic mapping between classes of characters (e.g. [a-z] -> [A-Z]). As far as I know this does not exist and you would have to write it yourself (except for the forementionned toUpperCase())

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

First argument is regular expression if substring matches with that pattern that will be    replaced by second argument ,if you want to convert to lowercase to upper case use

```
 toUpperCase()
```

method

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [jtr](http://jtr.sourceforge.net/). Example of usage:

```
String hello = "abccdefgdhcij";
CharacterReplacer characterReplacer;

try {
    characterReplacer = new CharacterReplacer("a-j", "Helo, Wrd!");
    hello = characterReplacer.doReplacement(hello);
} catch(CharacterParseException e) {
}

System.out.println(hello);
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```